# store.filter() not working as expected ember.js (Trying to search models)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to implement a search system here and I am having some trouble with store.filter()

First of all I can't find any good documentation on the `store.filter()` method aside from here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/

So I am using the example provided on that page as a guideline.

This is what I have in my code

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isDropdown: false,
    actions: {
        handle_search: function() {
            var search_text = this.get('search_text');
            if (search_text) {
                this.set('isDropdown', true);
                return this.store.filter('procedure', {proc_name: search_text}, function(procedure) {
                    console.log(procedure);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but when I log what is being returned, it's returning basically every single model. Instead of no results or a limited amount of results.

On top of that `procedure` it self is not the model's object, it's some other thing.

So my question is how do I get the actual model with the fields and how can I ensure that the store is actually filtering the results?

Comment: check the documentation here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L810. As a note, indeed, the log will log everything, you need to return 'true' for the records that you want return in that filter. Check the docs, I'm sure you'll be able to do it after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass in a function that returns true/false for including the record

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter('color', function(item){
      return item.get('color')=='red';
    });
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/647/edit

If you want to make a call back to the server at the same time (find by query) you include the optional query param, the below example will call `/colors?color=green`

````
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter('color', {color:'green'}, function(item){
      return item.get('color')=='red';
    });
  }
});

/**
    Takes a type and filter function, and returns a live RecordArray that
    remains up to date as new records are loaded into the store or created
    locally.

    The callback function takes a materialized record, and returns true
    if the record should be included in the filter and false if it should
    not.

    The filter function is called once on all records for the type when
    it is created, and then once on each newly loaded or created record.

    If any of a record's properties change, or if it changes state, the
    filter function will be invoked again to determine whether it should
    still be in the array.

    Optionally you can pass a query which will be triggered at first. The
    results returned by the server could then appear in the filter if they
    match the filter function.

    Example

    ```javascript
    store.filter('post', {unread: true}, function(post) {
      return post.get('unread');
    }).then(function(unreadPosts) {
      unreadPosts.get('length'); // 5
      var unreadPost = unreadPosts.objectAt(0);
      unreadPost.set('unread', false);
      unreadPosts.get('length'); // 4
    });
    ```

    @method filter
    @param {String or subclass of DS.Model} type
    @param {Object} query optional query
    @param {Function} filter
    @return {DS.PromiseArray}
  */
````

Comment: I'm slightly confused. The first parameter to filter, is that the model's name or the field that you want to filter by?

Comment: the first parameter is the model type, it correlates to `App.Color`

Comment: documentation added above.

Comment: Currently it does an exact match, is it possible for it to do a loose match and get all the results like that? 

Also how can I actually see which models it's returning in the console?

Comment: how would I check if 0 records were returned or nothing was found.

Comment: Yeah, both are possible, you just need to return true/false, so whatever logic you want is up to you. The second is a bit trickier, do you want to do something if it's empty?  It's a live collection, so empty now, doesn't mean always empty.

Comment: Just need to let the user know that no results were found. So I added a fount_results boolean variable on the controller that is set true to false per search. I just need to do a conditional check in my search results and be like if (array.length == 0) { set found_results to false) and so on.

For my first question about the logic, could you provide me with an example of how I can accomplish that?

Comment: It depends how you want to implement, if you want to do contains it'd be like this `item.get('color').contains('red')>=0;`

Comment: I ended up using indexOf instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write `indexOf`, glad you found it.

Comment: Wondering how to check if store.filter returned nothing meaning no search results were found.